# Losing "scroll" after dragging layout around

Tags: android, android-layout

I've implemented this code, that basically allows user to move a layout around the screen (Just Y axis):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{
TextView _view;
private int _yDelta;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    _view.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    view = (View) view.getParent();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (Y - _yDelta < -230 || Y - _yDelta > 160){
              //to avoid view going out of screen
            } else {
                lParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            }

            lParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(lParams);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

And this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/draggableContent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DRAGMEDRAGME DRAGME DRAGME DRAGME"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt cillum dolore eu it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt cillum dolore eu it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt cillum dolore eu it amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaturcillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaturcillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaturcillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaturcillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaturcillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaturcillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`textView1` is scrollable if I don't drag the "title". When I drag the title, whole layout (draggableContent - as `view.getParent()`) moves around. But, when I try to scroll that lorem ipsum, its not scrollable anymore.

Is there any way to fix this?

I've tried to find some parameter like "scrollable = true" but couldn't find that.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Instead of using a layout, I've replaced it all for a WebView, and happens exactly the same; without dragging, its scroll is working. Once you drag it around, scroll won't work anymore.

Comment: you are not calling super method onTouch

Comment: `super.onTouchEvent(event);`? Tried it, and didn't change.

Comment: here you are handling the `onTouch` event if the user is not dragging the title simply call `super.onTouchEvent(event);` like `return super.onTouchEvent(event);`

Comment: `return super.onTouchEvent(event);` instead of `return true`? With this replacement it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It was this line

```
lParams.bottomMargin = -250;
```

I just deleted it and its working good now.